# Launch image and icons for iOS applications on Qt Quick

Tags: ios, qt

I've tried to figure out how to add the icon of app and launch image following this guide (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ios-platform-notes.html#launch-images), but without any success.
I do not understand several, maybe the simplest, moments:

1) Where should the folder "ios" with Info.plist file be located? In root folder of project or in "Resource" folder? A little example or screenshot would be useful.

2) Can I change Info.plist directly in .pro-file before it will be generated by Qt? Or it is necessary to compose Info.plist manually and locate it in pre-created "ios"-folder?

3) Maybe, there is another way to set the launch image and app icon? Without touching .pro-file.

Will be glad of any help. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your questions:

1. This folder you may create manually and then put default Info.plist into.

Also you could edit default Info.plist in Xcode and the put them into ios folder (or other).

Follow the https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ios-platform-notes.html#information-property-list-files you need add this code to your pro-file (instead Qt Creator will replace Info.plist):

```
ios {
    QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = ios/Info.plist
}
```

2. Yes you can.

More of that - no best-practices-way to edit it maximally right by Qt tools. In first answer I wrote that you may edit default Info.plist in Xcode directly. (but don't forget copy it in your Qt-project)

3. To change app-icon of launch images no need to edit .pro file. You need to edit Info.plist generally.

You can do it in Xcode directly. But you need to do it every time after you make changes in your qt-project. I don't think that is correct way.

I answered to your several, simples questions. Hope thats helps!